# how to mandate com/net/etc in url using regex?

Tags: java, regex

i have below the regex. how can i mandate .com/net/etc?

```
String regex = "^(((https?|ftp)://|(www|ftp)\\.)[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)+([/?].*)?)|(http://)$";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you don't us a regex for this.

I'd recommend that you parse the URL using the `URL` class (or `URI` class if that is more appropriate), and then check that the hostname part ends with one of the required top-level domains.

I'd also recommend that you avoid hard-wiring a set of top-level domains into your code and/or your regexes.

- A whole swathe of new TLDs are going to go live fairly soon.  Like *thousands* of them ...
- Even ignoring the new TLDs, the set of 2-letter country TLDs is not fixed.  (Does South Sudan have a code yet?)

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do it:

```
[.](com|net|other)
```

But place it at the correct position in your big url regex (which is maybe not the best way to go...)

Answer (score 0):

After you validate URL protocol you may use something like ^[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET)$